# Reading text with sscanf and fgets

Tags: c

So my text file looks similar to this

```
1. First 1.1
2. Second 2.2
```

Essentially an integer, string and then a float.

Using `sscanf()` and `fgets()` in theory, I should be able to scan this in (I have to do it in this format) but only get the integer can someone help point what I am doing wrong?

```
while(!feof(foo))
{
  fgets(name, sizeof(name) - 1, foo);
  sscanf(name,"%d%c%f", &intarray[i], &chararray[i], &floatarray[i]);
  i++;
}
```

Where `intarray`, `chararray`, and `floatarray` are 1D arrays and `i` is an `int` initialized to 0.

Comment: Good use of `fgets/sscanf`, just needs a little fixing.

Answer (score 1):

The structure of the loop is wrong; you should not use `feof()` like that and you *must* always check the status of both `fgets()` and `sscanf()`.  This code avoids overflowing the input arrays, too.

```
enum { MAX_ENTRIES = 10 };
int   i;
int   intarray[MAX_ENTRIES];
float floatarray[MAX_ENTRIES];
char  chararray[MAX_ENTRIES][50];

for (i = 0; i < MAX_ENTRIES && fgets(name, sizeof(name), foo) != 0; i++)
{
    if (sscanf(name,"%d. %49s %f", &intarray[i], chararray[i], &floatarray[i]) != 3)
        ...process format error...
}
```

Note the major changes:

1. The dot after the integer must be scanned by the format string.
2. The `chararray` has to be a 2D array to make any sense.  If you read a single character with `%c`, it would contain the space after the first number, and the subsequent conversion specification (for the float value) would fail because the string name is not a floating point value.
3. The `&` in front of `chararray[i]` is not wanted when it is a 2D array.  It would be needed if you were really reading a single character in a 1D array of characters instead of the whole string such as 'First' or 'Second' from the sample data.
4. The test checks that three values were converted successfully.  Any smaller value indicates problems.  With `sscanf()`, you'd only get EOF returned if there was nothing in the string for the first conversion specification to work on (empty string, all white space); you'd get 0 returned if the first non-blank was alphabetic or a punctuation character other than `+` or `-`, etc.

If you really want a single character instead of the name, then you'll have to arrange to read the extra characters in the word, maybe using:

```
    if (sscanf(name,"%d %c%*s %f", &intarray[i], chararray[i], &floatarray[i]) != 3)
```

There's a space before the `%c` which is crucial; it will skip white space in the input, and then the `%c` will pick up the first non-blank character.  The `%*s` will read more characters, skipping any white space (there won't be any) and then scanning a string of characters up to the next white space.  The `*` suppresses an assignment; the scanned data won't be stored anywhere.

One of the major advantages of the `fgets()` plus `sscanf()` paradigm is that when you report the format error, you can report to the user the complete line of input that caused problems.  If you use raw `fscanf()` or `scanf()`, you can only report on the first character that caused trouble, typically up to the end of the line, and then only if you write code to read that data.  It is fiddlier (so the reporting is usually not very careful), and the available information is not as helpful to the user on those rare occasions when the reporting tries to be careful.

Answer (score 0):

won't it be %s for string else it will only read a character with %c and then the float value might be affected. 
try "%d %s %f"

%s won't help since it may read the float value itself. as far as I know, %c reads a single character. then it searches for a space that leads to problem. To scan the word, you can use a loop (terminated by a space ofcourse).

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your format string to:

```
"%d %s %f"
```

The spaces are because you have spaces in your input data, the `%s` because you want to read a multi-character string at that point (`%c` only reads one character); don't worry though, as `%s` won't read past a space. You'll need to make sure you've got enough space in the target buffer to read the string, of course.

If you only want the first character of the second word, try:

```
"%d %c%s %f"
```

And add an extra (dummy) buffer to receive the string parsed by `%s` which you want to discard.

Comment: So I tried changing it to %s, but it did not make a difference :/  sscanf(name,"%d %s %f", &intarray[i], &chararray[i], &floatarray[i]);